# Bootstrap button drop-down not under button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

So I have what should be an easy task that I just can't seem to find the answer to. The issue, of course, is somewhere in the CSS adjustment.

I have a bootstrap button group when includes a button dropdown. The group is pulled right inside a panel.

Here is a link to the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/32z3mx93/4/)

my button group looks like:

```
   <div class="btn-toolbar pull-right" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">
     <div class="dropdown">
                        <div class="btn-group-sm" role="group" aria-label="First group">
                            <a href="#" class="btn  btn-secondary dsbtnsec"> Favorite</a>
                                <button href="#" class="btn  btn-secondary dsbtnsec dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Graph Race <span class="caret"></span></button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Bar Chart</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Pie Chart</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            <a href="#" class="btn  btn-secondary dsbtnsec"> County View</a>
                            <a href="#" class="btn  btn-secondary dsbtnsec"> Explore Map</a>
                            <a href="#" class="btn  btn-secondary dsbtnsec"> Export Race &nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-export"></span></a>
                        </div>
       </div>
  </div>
```

The Graph Race drop-down works but isn't positioned under the button properly. I can't seem to figure out where the CSS issue is occurring. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

The issue happens with the default Bootstrap CSS so it's not something that I think I introduced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is the `btn-toolbar` class : `<div class="btn-toolbar pull-right" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">`

try this :
`<div class="pull-right" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">`

It's work for me : https://jsfiddle.net/4tgyu9u0/

Comment: That's it.  THanks!